# MoreLinq's Scan and For Loop returns different results

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

I need to compute `outputs` from `inputs` using the formula:

```
Output(i) = inputs(i) * factor + outputs(i - 1) * (1 - factor)
```

I implemented this using a `for` loop and MoreLinq's `Scan` extension:

```
Int32 p = 5;

Decimal factor = (Decimal) 2 / (p + 1);

List<Decimal?> inputs = Enumerable.Range(1, 40).Select(x => (Decimal?)x).ToList(); 

// Using Scan extension  

List<Decimal?> outputs1 = inputs.Scan((x, y) => x * factor + (y * (1 - factor)) ?? 0).ToList(); 

// Using for loop

List<Decimal?> outputs2 = new List<Decimal?> { inputs[0] };

for (int i = 1; i < inputs.Count(); i++) 
  outputs2.Add(inputs[i] * factor + (outputs2[i - 1] * (1 - factor)) ?? 0);
```

However, I get different outputs results. What am I missing?

Am I using `Scan` incorrectly?

Comment: What is `factor`?

Comment: @juharr how so?  I see `outputs2[0]` initialised and used in the calculation.  (although `inputs_` vs `inputs` difference.)

Comment: @juharr I am skipping the first value because for the first calculation it is impossible to get Output(I-1)

Comment: @zaggler just added the missing code

Comment: @GuruStron No, that was a typo when copying it to here. Just corrected the question.

Comment: @zaggler Just updated. It is compelling now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are interpreting parameters of `transformation` function in the wrong order (check out the [source code](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Scan.cs#L107) to see how `transformation` is invoked). Change your code to:

```
inputs.Scan((x, y) => y * factor + x * (1 - factor) ?? 0).ToList()
```

`x` is aggregator, i.e. previous value, y is the current one.